# How can I create a 3 Hectare circle around a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, circle

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can create a 3 Hectare circle around a point quickly? I am using arcmap 10.3.

Answer (score 10):

area=πr<sup>2</sup>

So you need to draw a buffer of 97.72m around your point.

You can use the Buffer tool in the toolbox for this. It is under 'Analysis > Proximity > Buffer' in the toolbox.